# Stenciljs how to check if slot is empty?

Tags: javascript, typescript, components, stenciljs, slot

How can i check if slot have value or is empty?

Here is my code:

```
  <div>
    <slot name="info"></slot>
  </div>
```

Here is pseudo code of what i need:

```
<div>

<slot name="info"></slot>

{this.info == null ? <p> No informations </p> : <p> {this.info.value} </p>}

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a reference to the host element of the component

```
@Element() hostElement: HTMLStencilElement;
```

and query for your slot as

```
this.hostElement.querySelector('[slot="slot1"]');
```

If it is falsy, it is not present

Comment: Your solution does work for initial render but I've found that (when using shadow DOM) an update is not always triggered when slot content changes.

In my situation I have a React component that renders the Stencil component with a named slot. I use `this.hostElement.querySelector('[slot="slot1"]');` to check whether anything's been passed to the specific slot. On initial render this is fine and works. However, no other updates to the slot content cause an update in the Stencil component except the first after the initial render

Comment: @lukenofurther found any solution other than a custom listener?

Comment: nope, I have no easy solution as yet